# Why do we search for square roots of 1 in Shor's algorithm unlike the quadratic sieve?

Tags: quantum-algorithms, mathematics, shors-algorithm

In the [quadratic sieve](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadratic_sieve) algorithm, the idea is to find $a$ and $a$ such that $a^2 \equiv b^2 \bmod n$. We need that $a\not\equiv \pm b \bmod n$. However, there the $c$ is not necessarily $1$. $\gcd(b \pm c,n)$ returns [non-trivial](https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/a/2452/26) factors.

However, in Shor's algorithm, we *specifically* need to find square roots of $1$ (in modulo $n$) i.e. we look for $a$ such that $a^2 \equiv 1 \bmod n$. That is, $b$ is *specifically* $1$. Why is this choice necessary?

---

**Related:** [Math SE: Chinese Remainder Theorem: four square roots of 1 modulo N](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2856758/chinese-remainder-theorem-four-square-roots-of-1-modulo-n)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The two problems are equivalent.

If you give me a pair $a, b$ such that $a^2 = b^2$ with $a \neq \pm b$ then $c = a b^{-1}$ satisfies $c \neq \pm 1$ and $c^2 = 1$.

If you give me a $c$ such that $c^2 = 1$ and $c \neq \pm 1$, and some target value $a$, then $b = a \cdot c$ satisfies $a^2 = b^2$ and $a \neq \pm b$.

You can derive a square root of 1 from an $a,b$ pair. You can derive an $a,b$ pair with desired $a$ from a square root of 1. They're reducible to each other.